# Populate elements of a matrix using values from a column

Tags: r

I am trying to populate a matrix using the values from a specific column (Dependent). In the example below in row 1 the Dependent value is 3 which will indicate a 1 in the 3rd column. Row 4 has a Dependent value of 2 so a 1 is put in column 2. I have considered using a for loop but was interested if there is a more elegant way of solving the problem.

```
Project Dependent   1   2   3   4
1         3                 1   
2                   
3                   
4         2             1
5         4                     1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For

```
Project <- 1:5
Dependent <- c(3, 0, 0, 2, 4)
df <- data.frame(Project, Dependent)
```

Create a matrix

```
m = matrix(nrow = max(df$Project), ncol = max(df$Dependent))
```

and populate it using a 2-column matrix of row and column vectors as indexes

```
m[as.matrix(df)] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what you described. hope it helps

```
Project<-1:5
Dependent<-c(3,0,0,2,4)
df<-data.frame(Project,Dependent)
df
Project Dependent
1       1         3
2       2         0
3       3         0
4       4         2
5       5         4

s<-matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = nrow(df))
for(i in 1:length(df$Dependent)) {
  if (i > 0 ) s[i,df$Dependent[i]]<-1 else NULL
}
s
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  [1,]   NA   NA    1   NA   NA
  [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  [4,]   NA    1   NA   NA   NA
  [5,]   NA   NA   NA    1   NA
```